# How to filter non-zero members in a large struct with gdb

Tags: c, linux, gdb

In type flow_t, most members' value is zero. I want to check which members' value is not 0.I use command `x/1920xb` to watch memory, but it's not convenient.

```
  typedef struct flow {
        ... // There are more than 100 members. Total size is 1920 bytes.
  }flow_t;
```

Comment: Why do you examine memory addresses instead of watch variables (specified by name)?

Comment: @e0k I thought gdb may have command to do it. Just because the member list is large. I have to check non-zero members one by one.

Comment: Or you can just write a C function to print non-zero members and call it from gdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in gdb.

It can be done with a bit of scripting.  There are, as usual, two basic approaches.

The "old school" approach is to use a combination of `set logging` and `shell` to get the effect you want: print the result to a file, then grep for the interesting parts.

The newer way would be to write a new command in Python.  This is not very difficult to do; you could look for the existing `pahole` script to see an example of walking a structure definition.